# What is the correct way to pass an Enum as an argument to a Fragment using Navigation Component safeargs

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-pass-data) discusses how to send simple integers and strings. For example:

```
<argument
    android:name="myIntArg"
    android:defaultValue="255"
    app:argType="integer" />
```

In the origin Fragment:

```
val action = OriginFragmentDirections.myAction(myInt)
findNavController().navigate(action)
```

In the destination Fragment:

```
val receivedInt = DestinationFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments).myIntArg
```

But say instead of `myIntArg`, I wanted to send an enum (`myEnumArg`). How would I do that? What **`app:argType`** would I use in my argument?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Edit:** As per the [Navigation 1.0.0-alpha08 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes#december_6_2018):

> Safe Args supports Serializable objects, including Enum values. Enum types can set a default value by using the enum literal without the class name (e.g. `app:defaultValue="READ"`) [b/111316353](https://issuetracker.google.com/111316353)

So this is now possible - you would use the name of your Enum class (i.e., `com.example.EnumClass`) or a relative name (`.EnumClass`) which will automatically prepend your app's package name to the class name.

*Previous answer:*

This is not possible with the current version of Navigation (1.0.0-alpha07), but the [existing feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111316353) is marked as fixed and the ability to use enums as arguments will be available in alpha08

Comment: Ah that's too bad. Any word on when alpha08 will be coming out?

Comment: Seems like it'll be [pretty soon](https://twitter.com/ianhlake/status/1068189435651534848)

Comment: Appreciate the info

Comment: Updated the answer now that Navigation 1.0.0-alpha08 is released with support for Enum classes.

Answer (score 23):

As @ianhanniballake mentioned in his updated answer, you need to use the latest version of Navigation.

Assume we have an **Enum** like below and your app package name is `com.example.app`.

```
package com.example.app.path.to.type.file

public enum class Type {
    First,
    Second,
    Third
}
```

Now we just need to declare the Arg like this:

```
<fragment
    ...>
    <argument
        android:name="type"
        android:defaultValue="Second"
        app:argType=".path.to.type.file.Type" />
...
</fragment>
```

Comment: How would you use this with compose navigation?

Answer (score 4):

For those wondering how this would be done with Compose, according to [NavType.EnumType](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/NavType.EnumType) you just use `NavType.EnumType`:

```kotlin
composable(
     YOUR_ROUTE,
     arguments = listOf(navArgument(ARGUMENT_NAME) {
                    type = NavType.EnumType(YOUR_ENUM::class.java)
                 }
     )
)
```

Comment: While this works, there is a problem how to retrieive a value from an argument. `backStackEntry.arguments?.get(ARGUMENT_NAME)` works, but it is deprecated. If use `getString` and other get-methods instead of `get` it returns `null`.